# Node.js - start command crashing node, but index.js running fine

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a node.js package where the index.js file works as expected.

But when I call

```
npm start
```

It crashes with the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! file /Users/martin.mcallister/Documents/leftovers/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Trailing comma in object at 24:1
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /Users/martin.mcallister/Documents/leftovers/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/martin.mcallister/Documents/leftovers/npm-debug.log
```

I've checked the package.json file. No comments. No errors as far as I can see. Here it is:

```
{
  "name": "leftovers",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Use your leftovers",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
}
```

Even if I remove the start line from the json and run `npm start` it still crashes with the error at the top.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you meant 'npm start'?

Comment: you're right. although still get an error. updated the post to reflect that. @MustSeeMelons

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after the dependencies block?

Comment: @ste2425 It was the trailing comma. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your error dude, it says that it can't parse your package.json, which is right:

```
{
  "name": "leftovers",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Use your leftovers",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/niazipan/leftovers#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
}
```

The comma on the line before the last line makes your package.json file invalid.